# Erro com Mysql - phpmyadmin: Access denied!

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

Estou com esse problema com phpmyadmin, estava funcionando normal, porem quando eu digitava: "mysql" no shell do linux ele não abria o mysql, só quando digitava: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root.

Então aí vi alguns artigos e modifiquei ou apaguei algo daí ta dando esse erro:

```
#2002 - Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado — 
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

Obs: Só instalei o xampp, daí já veio com mysql incluso, já tive esse problema uma fez no ubuntu não lembro como resolvi, estou usando manjaro.

Comment: Você não instalou uma em cima de outra ? Tive esse problema no ubuntu, mas eu havia instalado duas versões diferentes sem querer e uma bugava a outra

Comment: Olá, tudo bom @AnthraxisBR? Eu não lembro se tinha instalando o mysql via no manjaro, via pacman. Vou verificar isso, eu já tive esse problema também quando usava ubuntu e foi quase isso mesmo. Muito obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei um erro semelhando no [StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881123/mysqli-real-connect-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Ele sugere alterar **localhost** para **127.0.0.1** no arquivo config.inc.php (no XAMPP, este arquivo deve estar em `xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`).

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`

Veja se ajuda.

Comment: Olá Cleber! Parceiro deu certo essa dica muito obrigado. Eu já tinha visto ela, porem quando eu fiz esse processo não tinha dado certo por conta que essa linha de código estava comentada: //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; Logo quando retirei as barras deu certo, fica a dica pra mais alguém que tiver a mesma desatenção que eu. :)

Comment: É um prazer ajudar, Henrique! :D